# is it possible to change the Class of a Doctrine Object?

Tags: php, model, doctrine, entities

Im using Doctrine and I need to clone an object.

Two tables in the database have the same columns, but one exists for backlog orders whilst one is confirmed orders. Probably not the best way to do it, but they must be seperate as certain foreign keys cannot be satisfied on backlog objects.

So, I need to clone one object from the backlog and insert it into the current orders table. But if I clone the backlog order object, it will set the class to backlog order.

```
$backlog_orders = $this->Subscription_model->getBacklogOrders();
foreach($backlog_orders as $backlog_order){
    $new_order = new Entities\NewOrder;
    $new_order = clone $backlog_order;
    //Do other stuff to new order
    //At this point, I need to change the class of the object to NewOrder so that it will insert it into the correct table
    echo get_class($order); // Outputs BacklogOrder
    $this->Subscription_model->updateOrder($order); // Saves to DB
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I'd like to point out a mistake in your question, which kind of explains why you run into this.

> "But if I clone the backlog order object, it will set the class to backlog order."

Nothing gets set, in this point in your code..

```
$new_order = new Entities\NewOrder;
$new_order = clone $backlog_order;
```

..you first make a $new_order object and then make a new $new_order object which is a clone of $backlog_order. In other words, the first line with *new Entities\NewOrder* means absolutely nothing.

You also should know that the *clone* keyword in PHP makes a shallow copy. So all the references in $new_order are still to the old order. Even if you would manage to change the class in the way you are trying it right now doctrine would not do an insert but rather an update.

What you basically want is to make a true copy, which is not provided by PHP because it would violate the type system. In order to do this you should just fill $new_order with all the data from $backlog_order.

You should however also consider that you probably have an auto incrementing primary key right now. I don't know if doctrine will let you override this.

Comment: Great answer. Although I think doctrine automatically handles the primary keys. The $new_order = new Entities\NewOrder; is just to show that I was trying to set a neworder entity, but obviously cloning will create a new object of the type you are cloning.

I was thinking that it doesnt make much sense to do this when I was writing the question. I decided to do the copy manually through another method. I was hoping that setAll() would work, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you a specific answer but if you clone the object, you also clone its entity's primary key (order_id?), and I doubt Doctrine can handle this well.

I suggest you the to instance and persist a new object and use get/set like this:

```
$new_order = new Entities\NewOrder;
$new_order->setCustomer($backlog_order->getCutomer());
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing unfortunately. I was trying to be lazy and find a shortcut and was hoping someone would come up with a clever workaround

Comment: Don't be lazy =) This is the the cleanest way I think and also the best practice to fit software patterns.